using kotlin.reflect on the elements of a array not working
I am trying to use kotlin.reflect to get the names of variables in this array all. Then iterate over the array and get the name of each variable a, b, c. But well its not working and im not sure how to fix it
val a = "aa"
val b = "bb"
val c = "cc"
val all:Array<String> = arrayOf(a, b, c)

for (i in all) {
    println(::i.name) // References to variables and parameters are unsupported
}

This is just a dummy example

You can't because Kotlin doesn't store anything about where variables come from.
What you are using is a property reference which is specific to properties. In your case, i would be a local variable which doesn't really have a name at runtime (it's essentially just an element on the stack).
For example, take the following code:
//non-local
val origin = "a"
val intermediate = origin
val yourValue = intermediate;

println(::yourValue.name)

This code will output yourValue because ::yourValue refers to the property yourValue and not where the value originally came from (origin).
Now, if we slightly change your example to use a non-local variable for i, we could actually use a property reference and get a name but it's the name i of the element variable:
val a = "aa"
val b = "bb"
val c = "cc"
val all:Array<String> = arrayOf(a, b, c)
val i = all[0]

println(::i.name)//i

At the end, properties are (in most cases, at least on the JVM) just fields in a class which have a name accessible via Reflection but local variables cannot be accessed reflectively.
